# Unable to contact slurm controller

Tags: slurm

I followed the steps to troubleshoot here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/troubleshoot.html.

When running scontrol show slurmd, I get:

```
Active Steps             = NONE
Actual CPUs              = 1
Actual Boards            = 1
Actual sockets           = 1
Actual cores             = 1
Actual threads per core  = 1
Actual real memory       = 984 MB
Actual temp disk space   = 492 MB
Boot time                = 2019-03-27T17:53:56
Hostname                 = fedora2
Last slurmctld msg time  = NONE
Slurmd PID               = 1549
Slurmd Debug             = 4
Slurmd Logfile           = /var/log/slurmd.log
Version                  = 17.11.13-2
```

I don't know why slurmd on fedora2 can't communicate with the controller on fedora1. slurmctld daemon is running fine on fedora1.

The slurm.conf is as follows:

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator easy.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
#SlurmctldHost=fedora1
#
ControlMachine=fedora1
ControlAddr=192.168.1.4 
MailProg=/bin/mail 
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-# 
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm/slurmctld.pid
#SlurmctldPort=6817 
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm/slurmd.pid
#SlurmdPort=6818 
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
SlurmdUser=root 
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/affinity
# 
# 
# TIMERS 
#KillWait=30 
#MinJobAge=300 
#SlurmctldTimeout=120 
#SlurmdTimeout=300 
# 
# 
# SCHEDULING 
FastSchedule=1
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
# 
# 
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING 
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
ClusterName=fedora
#JobAcctGatherFrequency=30 
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=verbose 
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=verbose 
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmd.log
# 
# 
# COMPUTE NODES 
NodeName=fedora1 NodeAddr=192.168.1.4 CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=fedora2 NodeAddr=192.168.1.5 CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN 
PartitionName=debug Nodes=fedora[1-2] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

The output of tail /var/log/slurmd.log on fedora2, on multiple lines:

`error: Unable to register: Unable to contact slurm controller (connect failure)`

Comment: I encounter the same problem. My situation is `slurmd` is installed on fedora.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a error similar message (although the error for me was written to `/var/log/messages`).  The problem for me was that `yum` was installing `slurmd` on the compute nodes from the EPEL repo (I think this must have been a new addition because this didn't happen previously), instead of from a local repo.

My `slurmctld` on the SLURM controller node was version 20.02.4 while EPEL's version of `slurmd` was 20.11.2.  When reinstalling `slurm` via `yum`, I specified installing the correct version (which picked it up from my local repo), i.e. `yum install slurmd-20.02.4`.

Once `slurmd` and `slurmctld` were the same version, everything worked as expected.